# Push an array of documents embedded in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection in the following format

```
{Name: "Asd", Age: 23}
```

I want to add an array of documents such that the final collection looks like

```
{
    Name: "Asd", 
    Age: 23, 
    Address: [
        {City: "Tokyo", Country: "Japan"},
        {City: "Beijing", Country: "China"}
    ]
}
```

Tried the following code in pymongo

```
db.collection.update({Name:"Asd", Age:23},{"$push":{"address":{"City:"Tokyo",Country:"Japan"}}},upsert=True)
```

receiving the following error:

> The field 'address' must be an array but is of type Object in document

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a typo in your query:

{"`City:"`Tokyo",Country:"Japan"}

Following update works in `mongo` shell:

```
db.collection.update( {Name: "Asd", Age: 23}, {$push:{ "Address":{"City":"Tokyo",Country:"Japan"} }}, {upsert:true})
```

Comment: The typo has been rectified. Error still throws up. Is it something specific to pymongo

Answer (score 0):

What version of MongoDB and pymongo are you using? I tested the below code using MongoDB 3.2.8 and pymongo 3.2.2, and it seems to work as expected:

```
import pymongo
db = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017').get_database('test')
db.test.update( {'Name':'Asd', 'Age':23}, {'$push':{'address':{'City':'Tokyo', 'Country':'Japan'}}}, upsert=True)
db.test.update( {'Name':'Asd', 'Age':23}, {'$push':{'address':{'City':'Beijing', 'Country':'China'}}}, upsert=True)
```

This resulted in:

```
> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "Name": "Asd",
  "Age": 23,
  "address": [
    {
      "City": "Tokyo",
      "Country": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "City": "Beijing",
      "Country": "China"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that the `update()` method is [deprecated](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) in the latest version of pymongo. It will be replaced by `update_one()` and `update_many()` in the future.